# Execute command line from C program

Tags: c, winapi, cmd

I need to execute the following command from a c program:

```
clamscan.exe -r C:\testing -d"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\.clamwin\db" -lC:\testing\results.txt
```

I am trying to use the CreateProcess function as follows:

```
res = CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd.exe /c C:\\Program Files\\ClamWin\\bin\\clamscan.exe -r C:\\testing -d \"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\.clamwin\db\" -lC:\\testing\\results.txt" , NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

with the following error handling:

```
if(res!=0) {
// Wait till cmd do its job
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    // Check whether our command succeeded?
    GetExitCodeProcess( pi.hProcess, &dwErr );
    // Avoid memory leak by closing process handle
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
} else {
    printf("not done");
    dwErr = GetLastError();
}
```

When I run the program, I receive the following error twice in a messagebox:

```
cmd.exe - Application Error
The application failed to initialize properly (0x0000005).  Click on OK to terminate the application.
```

Can anyone help me understand what's the problem?  I have even tried passing "cmd.exe" as lpCommandLine but I still get the same error.

Comment: drop the cmd.exe and launch "C:\\Program Files\\ClamWin\\bin\\clamscan.exe " directly

Comment: Tried it out and I am getting the same error.

Comment: I think you also need to escape the backslashes in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\.clamwin\db`, so `C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\.clamwin\\db`.

Comment: Tried it out but still not working.

Comment: We can't tell what you did since you didn't edit your question. Your strings are kind of a mess, with some backslashes properly escaped and others not. Please post your actual code rather than just saying "tried that, didn't work."

Answer (score 2):

I see the following problems:

1. You don't escape all the backslash characters.
2. There's no need for cmd here. Start the executable directly.
3. The second parameter to `CreateProcess` expects a modifiable buffer, but you pass a literal. You usually get away with it using ANSI because of an implementation detail. But formally it is wrong. Pass a modifiable buffer.

The other thing that could be an issue is how you declared and initialized `si`. We cannot see that code.

Of course, perhaps your code is fine, but the other application is gagging.

Comment: Failing to initialize `si` is a very common mistake.